# Auto resize textarea diagonally to fit content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to auto-resize my textarea diagonally to fit content.

I was seeing a jsfiddle demo but there the textarea is resized just by height. Is it possible to auto-resize diagonally?

Comment: the jsfiddle link :  http://jsfiddle.net/ImpressiveWebs/fGNNT/1333/

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 txt.on('keyup', function () {

        content = $(this).val();

        content = content.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
        hiddenDiv.html(content + '<br class="lbr">');

        $(this).css('height', hiddenDiv.height()+50);
        $(this).css('width', $(this).width()+50);
    });
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. This is increasing the width abnormally. I need to auto-resize it diagonally. As in using aspect ration.